# How to receive associative array data with 'FormCollection' in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following data to send ajax call to the controller action:

```
var data = {
    "PersonalInfo": [
        {      
            "FirstName": "Leonel",
            "LastName": "Messi"     
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Cristiano",
            "LastName": "Ronaldo" 
        }
    ]
};
```

Ajax call method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Create",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: (JSON.parse(data)).PersonalInfo,
    success: function (response) { }                       
});
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    base.Create(formCollection);
}
```

In server side, I need array/list of `FormCollection`, e.g.:

```
formCollection[0] = {      
    "FirstName": "Leonel",
    "LastName": "Messi"     
}

formCollection[1] = {      
    "FirstName": "Cristiano",
    "LastName": "Ronaldo"      
}
```

Or something like following code so that I can call `base.Create(formCollection)` method multiple times for multiple personal info.

```
public ActionResult Create(List<FormCollection> formCollection)
{

}
```

But it is not possible, are there any alternative for this context?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `FormCollection`? Use a model with `FirstName` and `LastName` properties and bind to a collection of your model - `public ActionResult Create(List<Person> model)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use formcollection?

Visual studio has a special menu option selection that can consume a JSON object and output a class that the modelbinder maps to. Copy your expected JSON result (data object).

Go to a class file, then go to visual studio's menu bar, `Edit` => `Paste Special` => `Paste JSON as classes`.

Use the resulting classes as the argument to your api controller action call and they should map.

Comment: I need to call  `base.Create(formCollection)` method. If I create class from Json object, then cannot call  `base.Create(formCollection)`. Because  `base.Create(className)` shows error message.
Thank you for your reply.......